# User Enabled but not Activated

Tags: user, joomla-3.6

I could see few users in Joomla User Manager as below

```
Enabled = true
Activated = false
Last Visit Date = 2015-10-31 12:06:20
```

It looks weird, how a user is enabled without activation?

Note: Right from the first day, the new user account activation is 'Self'

Answer (score 5):

Enabled allows a user to login at will. If you switch Enabled for a user to 'off' they won't be able to get into their account. Activated however only happens one time usually by the administrator, or if set up in such a way through an activation link (by email for instance). Once an account is activated you can't deactivate it. Another word you could substitute for Activated here would be 'validated'.

Comment: Validated definitely sounds like the right term. Activated is weird. Joomla devs have done quite some weird ux choices and this seems one of them. However, one should be aware that it is possible to have a activated=false user, who has a last visit date. This probably means he/she visited but did not validated his/her email.